# cortex-m0 systick interrupt doesn't happens

Tags: stm32, cortex-m

I am writting firmware for stm32f072.
The problem is that SysTick interrupt doesn't happens.
Here is simple code for SysTick configuring:

```
SysTick_Config(1000);
```

This function is taken from CMSIS's core_cm0.h file:

```
    __STATIC_INLINE uint32_t SysTick_Config(uint32_t ticks)
{
  if ((ticks - 1) > SysTick_LOAD_RELOAD_Msk)  return (1);      /* Reload value impossible */

  SysTick->LOAD  = (ticks & SysTick_LOAD_RELOAD_Msk) - 1;                                  /* set reload register */
  NVIC_SetPriority (SysTick_IRQn, (1<<__NVIC_PRIO_BITS) - 1);  /* set Priority for Systick Interrupt */
   SysTick->VAL   = 0;                                          /* Load the SysTick Counter Value */
  SysTick->CTRL  = SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Msk |
                   SysTick_CTRL_TICKINT_Msk   |
                   SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;                    /* Enable SysTick IRQ and SysTick Timer */
  return (0);                                                  /* Function successful */
}
```

System timer counts as expected.

SysTick->CTRL's overcounting bit is set to 1 but there is no interrupt happens! Firmware doesn't jump to SysTick_Handler().
[image]
What I miss? This code is enough for stm32f1 and stm32f4 devices but not work for stm32f0.

Comment: Are you sure you have interrupt vectors initialized? Do you have `startup_stm32f0xx.s` included in your project?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look at the [Code Snippets from ST](http://www.st.com/stm32snippets). These are low level programs for F0 (and L0) families. Some of them use the SysTick (e.g. first two example from CLOCK CONTROLLER projects) and all things are preconfigured and hopefully works on your board too. It is written originally for the STM32F072 Discovery board. I used it with my custom board with some tiny modifications.